# How To Make Sitecore Workflow Comments Mandatory For Specific Item

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-workflow

I have a requirement to make workflow comments mandatory for a specific type of item.
I am trying to override the workbox comment method .

If anyone has worked on something like this plese help me here.

Comment: have you tried to assign the Required validation rule to the Comments field to your Comment template?

Comment: Yes ..But I need to make it conditional like for some types of item it should not allow . So I am trying with a custom  rule. will update if that works.

Comment: It sounds like you could define a separate workflow where the comments are mandatory, and assign that workflow to the template's default workflow in standard values. Or is it even more specific than just all items on the same template?

Comment: Yes. We can have another workflow. Its just more specific to item types.